# Android Button Doesn't Work; Other Buttons Do Work Though

Tags: android, eclipse, button

I have an app that contains two buttons, both that are suppose to take the user to the same page.
Here is the .java file for them:

```
public class PageTwoActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.page2);

        Button home = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ButtonHome);
        home.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), GuideApplicationActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);


    Button home2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ButtonHome2);
    home2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent myIntent2 = new Intent(view.getContext(), GuideApplicationActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(myIntent2, 0);
        }



});}





});};};
```

Any help? If you need to see any other files, please ask.
Thanks in advance,

Comment: What do you mean by doesnt work? are you getting any errors?

Comment: if it doesn't work so tell us what do you mean? are you getting some Exception (if yes , so add the logCat) ? or nothing at all ? ..etc , we need more details :) and we can help you , because you code seems good and should be working like a charm ;)

Comment: yeah , your code and the `});};};` at the end of your file ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something is wrong with your opening and closing tags. Try this:

```
public class MainMenu extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.page2);

    Button home = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ButtonHome);
    home.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), GuideApplicationActivity.class);
        startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
        }
        });

Button home2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ButtonHome2);
home2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent myIntent2 = new Intent(view.getContext(), GuideApplicationActivity.class);
        startActivityForResult(myIntent2, 0);
    }
});
}
}
```

Comment: This worked, thanks! :) Also, I apologise for not making my post clear by posting error logs, I am fairly new to the developing scene. I will bear that in mind for future posts.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this code inside your `onClick(...)` method.

```
        Intent myIntent2 = new Intent(PageTwoActivity.this, GuideApplicationActivity.class);
        PageTwoActivity.this.startActivityForResult(myIntent2, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

i think that you have doing something wrong in your code . try this :

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;


public class PageTwoActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.page2);

        Button home = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ButtonHome);
        home.setOnClickListener(this);


    Button home2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ButtonHome2);
    home2.setOnClickListener(this);

 }

@Override
public void onClick(View v){
Intent myIntent  = new Intent(this, GuideApplicationActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
}
}
```

**NB :** your Activity `GuideApplicationActivity` ***should be declared*** on your Manifest File